# Python lambda function in sorted()

Tags: python, dictionary

This woking code gives me the 5 most relevant documents for a topic out of my corpus.

```
most_relevant_docs = sorted(bow_corpus, reverse=True, key=lambda doc: abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0))) 
print most_relevant_docs[ :5]
```

But since the corpus is not readable by human I want to zip an index to the corpus so I can recover the depending documents.

```
corpus_ids = range(0,len(corpus))
most_relevant_docs = sorted(zip(corpus_ids, bow_corpus), reverse=True, key=lambda my_id, doc : abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0)))
print most_relevant_docs[ :5]
```

Where do I have to adapt the lambda function so it returns the id together with the document?

Comment: Can you mock up some data so we can visualize what you are trying to achieve? Of course, as it stands, we can't run any of your code.

Comment: the lambda is used as a key only, will not modify the structure of the output but the order of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sortingFunc = lambda doc: abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0))
corpus_ids = range(0,len(corpus))
most_relevant_docs = sorted(zip(corpus_ids, bow_corpus), reverse=True, key=lambda pair: sortingFunc(pair[1]))
```

When you zip it, each element becomes like `(index, value)`, so the original sorting key wouldn't work. You'd need to modify it so it sorts by the value as opposed to the pair